# Plotly + Reveal.js: plot is moved outside of my slide

Tags: html, plotly, reveal.js

I am trying to use plotly on a slide in reveal.js. 
However, my plot is not in the middle of the slide but rather it moves somewhere below.

Screenshot:
[image: the problem]

Here is the code of my slide (presentationEntryPoint eventually draws in 'some_plot'):

```
  <section>
    <h3>Plot</h3>
    <div id='some_plot'> </div>
    <script>presentationEntryPoint('some_plot', {
        name: 'remove 0',
        size: 10000,
        algorithm: 'std::remove',
        type: 'int',
        time: 'y',
        padding: 'x',
        group: 'intel_9700K',
        percentage: 50,
      }, []);
    </script>
  </section>
```

UPD: Can be seen here: https://denisyaroshevskiy.github.io/my_first_simd_1_presentation/#/2
Some times requires an update or two.
Safari, Chrome and Yandex Browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `class="r-stretch"` on your plot div.